# Using JSON to display the data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am a new to JSON, I am trying to make the menu that can click and display the data.
All the objects are return from the Controller of my asp.net mvc project.

This is my code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function ViewProduct() {
    var searchVal = $("#txtsearch").val();
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      var mainMenu = $("#content ul#navmenu-v");
      $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {
        var new_li = $("<li class='level1' id='select_list'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='" + dataOption.ID + "' class ='selectedcategory'>" + dataOption.Name + "</a>");
        mainMenu.append(new_li);
        $('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
        var urlGetProByDep = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetProductsByDepList";
        t = dataOption.ID;
        var data = {};
        if (searchVal != "") {
          data.depID = t;
          data.Q = searchVal;
        } else {
          data.depID = t;
        }
      $(".brand_id").empty();
      $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
         $(".brand_id").empty();
         $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
            $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
               $(".brand_id").html( value.Name + "</br>" + value.PictureName + "</br>" + value.ID);
            });
         });
      });
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   ViewProduct(); 
});
```

The other block of menu code works very well , just have a problem with this block of my code above :

```
      $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
         $(".brand_id").empty();
         $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
            $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
               $(".brand_id").html( value.Name + "</br>" + value.PictureName + "</br>" + value.ID);
            });
         });
      });
```

It is the block that I take the the object of JSON to display the in my view, but when I click on the menu , It shows only the element at the last of JSON object.

This is my JSON :

```
{"ja":
   [
       {"Name":"ABC1","PictureName1":"my image name1","ID":1},   
       {"Name":"ABC2","PictureName2":"my image name2","ID":2}
]}
```

Each menu is the department of each product. And if I do not loop the product data in the menu block, I cannot take the ID of the department to query to get the product in each department.

Any idea or question are welcome, Thanks you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a copy&paste-error in your code, you will do 2 request to exactly the same url after each other - not even using the results of the first request. I guess you only wanted something like

```
$(".brand_id").empty();
$.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
    $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
         $(".brand_id").html( value.Name + "</br>" + value.PictureName + "</br>" + value.ID);
    });
});
```

But your problem is the `.html()` method. You are looping over your products, and in each turn you set the html of *each* `.brand_id`-element to a new value. So the result you see is what you have set to all elements in the last iteration. What you would need to do is set the HTML of each element on its own, each with a different content.

Yet, instead of emptying the list items and readding new contents to them (maybe the number of your products changes each query request), I'd rather remove all items and append new ones:

```
$(".brand_id").remove();
$.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
    var $parent = $("#parent"); // the parent node of the product list
    $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
         $parent.append('<li class="brand_id">' + value.Name + '<br />' + value.PictureName + '<br />' + value.ID + '</li>');
    });
});
```

(edit) ...or, if `brand_id` really is an id:

```
var $parent = $("#brand_id").empty();
$.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
    $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
         $parent.append('<div>' + value.Name + '<br />' + value.PictureName + '<br />' + value.ID + '</div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and any way `brand_id` is the class of the `<a href>` not the list.

Comment: I couldn't see the elem type of .brand_id in your code, but the answer matches still. You'd need to use append(), html() will overwrite the content set in the pregoing iteration.

Comment: OK , thanks. But now one product is loop 21 times in my page. I don't know why.

Comment: I mean, `value.Name` has 21 times in my page.

Comment: You said so already. How many elements does the $parent selector match? You should have *one* Node that is cleared and then filled the new items (one element per iteration).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10832/discussion-between-socheata-and-bergi)

Answer (score 1):

You are subscribing to the `.click` event of the anchor inside a `$.each` call. But since you have captured the `dataOption` variable you are using to prepare the AJAX request in a closure, it is obvious that by the time you click on the link, this `dataOption` variable is already pointing to the last element of the array you are looping over. So you could pass the argument to the click callback like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewProduct() {
        // TODO: There's some url variable used here which is nowhere defined => define it
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var mainMenu = $("#content ul#navmenu-v");
            $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {
                $(mainMenu)​.append(
                    $('<li/>', {
                        'class': 'level1',
                        // TODO: find an unique id or you get broken HTML
                        'id': 'select_list',
                        'html': $('<a/>', {
                            'href': '#',
                            'id': dataOption.ID,
                            'class': 'selectedcategory',
                            'text': dataOption.Name,
                            'click': function(arg) {
                                return menuClick(arg);
                            }({ dataOption: dataOption })
                        })
                    })
                );​
            });
        });
    }

    function menuClick(arg) {
        var urlGetProByDep = '<%= Url.Action("GetProductsByDepList", "Products") %>';
        var t = arg.dataOption.ID;
        var data = { };
        var searchVal = $('#txtsearch').val();
        if (searchVal != '') {
            data.depID = t;
            data.Q = searchVal;
        } else {
            data.depID = t;
        }

        $('.brand_id').empty();

        var url = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "ProductListing") %>';

        // TODO: Are those 2 nested AJAX calls really necessary here?
        $.getJSON(url, data, function (product) {
            $('.brand_id').empty();
            $.getJSON(url, data, function (product) {
                $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
                    $('.brand_id').html( value.Name + "</br>" + value.PictureName + "</br>" + value.ID);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(ViewProduct);
</script>
```

Also notice that I have moved the `searchVal` declaration inside the click callback in order to account for changes of its value between the time the page is loaded and the user actually clicking on the link.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, But I got an error `Error: illegal character,Source Code:$(mainMenu)?.append( `

Comment: I solved it, because I copied the code from the site, maybe it error with the sign. Now no more error But There is no any data display on my page.

Comment: Did you look in your FireBug console to see if there are some other errors? Also are the AJAX requests being sent with the correct data?

Comment: `<ul id="navmenu-v"> </ul>` It is empty <ul> in my fire bug.

Comment: Is the `$.each` executed? In the first `$.getJSON` call you seem to be using some `url` variable which you haven't declared anywhere.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: There's nothing wrong with adding the click handlers inside a .each, is it?

Comment: @Bergi, no there's nothing wrong. You just must be careful what variables you are using inside those event handlers. In this example the OP didn't use it correctly because he used the `dataOption` inside his click event handler and this variable is the current item of each iteration. So in this case when the user clicks on the link this variable is obviously pointing to the last element of the array you are looping over because the `$.each` has finished executed long before this click callback is invoked.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Why should the value of `dataOption` change between the handler registration and execution? He is creating a valid closure, to which `dataOption` is a function argument. There is no "array", that's the advantage of using iterator functions.